# Best practice for writing a custom portion of code?

Tags: c#, .net, svn, standards

Found thinking of a title a little tricky, but basically my question is how do you keep a system as generic (right term?) as possible when needing to write customer special code.

My scenario is that we have a standard system that lives in the trunk of subversion. Sometimes customers want to make a change that does not conform to that standard system, so our practice is to usually branch off the code and develop on that branch, but then it gets messy when trunk work needs to be included in a customer special or if an idea a customer wants needs to be in both the branch and trunk.

Is there a better way or standard to deal with such requests because it seems everything coded is very specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly a difficult scenario.

One option might be to have configuration to stipulate whether a feature is turned on or not - so the feature goes into the main branch but you only set the config to true for the customer(s) that require it.  It's still a bit messy but I think it's cleaner than having multiple branches per customer.

In more complex scenarios you can develop new functionality as a type of 'plug in' architecture, where you have different implementations implementing the same interface - some type of factory could decide which to load.

I don't think there is any magic bullet for maintaining a generic code base which is subject to differing customer requests.

Comment: A plug in route seems to be one of the best options where we have our base standard system, then drop on any customer specials.

Comment: it might mean a lot of refactoring at the beginning, but I'd say it will probably pay dividends - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In terms of improving code re-usability, there are usually several parts:

## Language Features

Being able to interchange smaller parts of an application is a core language design concern. Many languages are designed with methods of maximizing re-usability. Here are some examples (some are C# specific):

- Interfaces
- Generics
- Co/Contra-variance
- Dependency Injection
- Design patterns (specifically, ones related to structure or creation)

They will allow you to reuse your codebase more easily but, on their own, aren't a golden bullet.

## Project Design

Even if you exploit every feature available in C#, a insufficiently thought out project will probably be difficult to interchange. I'd reccomend any larger solutions should be split into logical, independant, subunits. Again, an example of a solution structure might be:

```
MyProgram // Wires up components and subunits.
MyProgram.Core // Contains a core 'kernel' for your application
MyProgram.IO // Contains generic interfaces and implementations for performing IO
MyProgram.UI // Contains UI code that displays and interacts with your core. The core should not depend on UI elements.
MyProgram.Models // Contains structure of databases, data models other components may act on
MyProgram.Models.Serialization // Converts your models for IO etc. Maybe you want MyProgram.IO to be generic enough to reuse.
Helpers // Generic helpers that you tend to use in multiple applications. You will want these  to be in a standalone repository so that you can keep the classes validated.
```

## Versioning

Ultimately, you may not be able to handle -every- problem with language features and good project design. If you have an awkward client request, sometimes you might want to pull (not branch) the components you -can- reuse and branch the ones you need to edit.